# QT Table cell edit error : only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`)

Tags: pandas, pyqt5

Using QT Python. In QTableView display dataframe laoded from csv file. I then edit cell and I get error. Example change: value from 40, 45, after double click.

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/villa/PycharmProjects/ForecastAPP/Forecastapp_02.py", line 96, in setData
    self._df.values[row][col] = value
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

In debug error in

```
    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
        print(row)
        print(col)
        print(value)
        self._df.values[row][col] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True
```

complete class

```
class PandasModel_1(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df = pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self._df = df
        self.setChanged = False
        self.dataChanged.connect(self.setModified)

    def setModified(self):
        self.setChanged = True
        print(self.setChanged)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QVariant()
        elif orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QVariant()

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if (role == Qt.EditRole):
                return self._df.values[index.row()][index.column()]
            elif (role == Qt.DisplayRole):
                return self._df.values[index.row()][index.column()]
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
        print(row)
        print(col)
        print(value)
        self._df.values[row][col] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending= order == Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

called in

```
    def loadFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", "", "CSV Files (*.csv)");
        self.pathLE1.setText(fileName)
        df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
        model = PandasModel_1(df)
        print(model)
        self.history1_data.setModel(model)
        self.history1_data.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked)
        self.history1_data.setSelectionBehavior(self.history1_data.SelectRows)
        self.history1_data.setSelectionMode(self.history1_data.SingleSelection)
```

complete program

```
"""
@author: Pino Villa, app to manage ARIMA forecast . Version 2 load data into table and matplotplot
"""
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDoubleValidator
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
import pandas as pd
from PandasModel import PandasModel
from PandasModel_panda import PandasModel_panda
from tablemodel_editable import PandasModelx
from cnt_init_values import CntInitialValues
import sys, os
import warnings
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
#plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QDir, QItemSelectionModel, QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex, QVariant, QSize, QSettings
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QTableView, QApplication, QToolBar, QLineEdit, QComboBox, QDialog,
                             QAction, QMenu, QFileDialog, QAbstractItemView, QMessageBox, QWidget)
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

FORM_CLASS,_=loadUiType(resource_path("main2.ui"))

import sqlite3

class PandasModel_1(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df = pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self._df = df
        self.setChanged = False
        self.dataChanged.connect(self.setModified)

    def setModified(self):
        self.setChanged = True
#

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QVariant()
        elif orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QVariant()

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if (role == Qt.EditRole):
                return self._df.values[index.row()][index.column()]
            elif (role == Qt.DisplayRole):
                return self._df.values[index.row()][index.column()]
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
        print(row)
        print(col)
        print(value)

        self._df.values[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending= order == Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

class Main(QMainWindow, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Main,self).__init__(parent)
        app = QApplication([])
        app.setStyle('Fusion')
        self.history1_data = QTableView()
        self.model = PandasModel_1()
        self.history1_data.setModel(self.model)
        self.history1_data.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked)
        self.history1_data.setSelectionBehavior(self.history1_data.SelectRows)
        self.history1_data.setSelectionMode(self.history1_data.SingleSelection)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Handel_Buttons()

    def Handel_Buttons(self):
        self.loadhist_btn.clicked.connect(self.GET_DATA) # this is for sqlite
#        self.corr_btn_1.clicked.connect(self.getCorr)
        self.load_file_btn.clicked.connect(self.loadFile) # this is for csv then pandas

    def GET_DATA(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect(resource_path("parts.db")) # Connect to Sqlite3 database ad fill GUI table with data
        cursor = db.cursor()
        command = ''' SELECT * from Superstore2csv '''
        result = cursor.execute(command)
        self.table1.setRowCount(0)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.table1.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.table1.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
    def loadFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", "", "CSV Files (*.csv)");
        self.pathLE1.setText(fileName)
        df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
        self.model = PandasModel_1(df)
        self.history1_data.setModel(self.model)
        self.history1_data.selectRow(0)
        self.save_file_btn_1.clicked.connect(self.Event1) # update dataframe

    def Event1(self):
        print(self.model.setChanged)
        if  self.model.setChanged == True:
            print(self.table.df)
        else:
            print("nothing changed. goodbye")

    def dataframe_output(self):

        print('\nUpdated DataFrame:')
        print(self.df_table)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you setting labels for columns (possibly by creating the dataframe using a dictionary)?

Comment: You're setting the model on the `self.history1_data` table, but that table is *never* shown. You're probably trying to edit another table that already exists on your UI file.

Comment: Also, when a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is requested, it *MUST* be *both* minimal *and* reproducible. Your code has lots of imports that are completely unnecessary for the example, while others are completely unknown. Please, carefully read the above link, take your time, reduce your code and ensure that we can copy, paste and run it.

Answer (score 0):

[`columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) returns *labels* of the columns; by default they are integers representing the column index, but if you use strings you obviously cannot use them for `values`, since it's an index-based array.

In any case, there's no need to use the dataframe indexes, as QModelIndex already provides them, and you should use those parameters instead.

```
self._df.values[index.row()][index.column()] = value
```

Comment: By changing to: self._df.values[index.row()][index.column()] = value resolves the error but after changing cell value from 40 to 45 and press enter the cell value remains original value to 40. I need to be able to change many values then press the pushbutton to update cell values changes to dataframe and then to SQL . I prefer using QTableView with pandas dataframe in that I can maniplulate dafaframe (example pivot) and the load to Table View

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean. If you change cell data, it automatically sets the value on the model, so "then press the pushbutton to update cell values changes to dataframe and then to SQL" doesn't make a lot of sense, and it's also not really clear how you're actually using the model. Also, you never mentioned using a SQL model as reference. I suggest you to edit your question and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For now ignore SQL. I just need to edit cell and then update dataframe with cell change. There is a lot of example how to populate QtableView but not many good examples of cell edit.  By changing to this self._df.values[index.row()][index.column()] = value resolved the error and 'value' in debug contains the changed value but when I press enter the cell returns to original value . Not sure what I am missing to retain changed value

Comment: Using setData is enough, so the problem might be somewhere else in your code, as I just made a test with your model and editing correctly updates the model. As requested, edit your question and provide a MRE.

Comment: hi, here is complete program